# How to get value displayed in image created by Base64-encoded string?

Tags: ruby, image-processing, encoding, base64, ocr

I have a Base64-encoded string that is used as the source of an image element on a website and need to derive the value from said string.  Is there any tool that allows this information to be extracted from an image based on the bits returned by decoding the Base64 string?  An example is here:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

This returns an image containing the value 210000, but I need some way, if possible to return that actual value.

If the only answer is some sort of OCR technology, any advice on where to start, specifically related to embedding this in a Ruby script, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The expected output is not clear.

Comment: The expected output I would want is the value - 210000 in this example.

Answer (score 3):

I have just tried your example with [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_recognize_only_digits?), an open OCR system, on an Ubuntu command line.

Going from base64 to digits looked like this:

`$ base64 -d image.base64 | tesseract - - digits | sed -e 's/\ //g'`

With the output:

`210000`

I'm afraid I don't know how that would integrate with Ruby, but I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this myself today, here's what I came up with:

```
File.open('im.png','wb'){|f| f << Base64.decode64(src.sub('data:image/png;base64,',''))}
num = `tesseract -psm 8 -l eng im.png - digits`.gsub(/\D/,'')
```

I had to `apt-get install tesseract-ocr` and download the traineddata:

wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/master/eng.traineddata

sudo mv -v eng.traineddata /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/